# Node.js PostgreSQL single quote issue with prepared query

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sails.js

I have an issue with an INSERT query in PostgreSQL and Node.js

It looks like values containing a single quote like "L'Ange" isn't passing through the query :

```
connection.query('insert into my_table (name) select $1', {name : "L'ange"}, function ...
```

Error

> [error: syntax error at or near "Ange"]

Any idea ?

I already tried, various sql escapes, even the npm module "pg-escape", nothing works...
Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried putting the quote in quote i.e. 3 single name : "L'''ange"

Comment: what library do you use?

Comment: Have you tried to escape the single qoute like `connection.query('insert into my_table (name) select $1', {name : "L\'ange"}, function ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can always escape single quotes by doubling it like

```
connection.query('insert into my_table (name) select $1', {name : "L''ange"}, function ...
```

Comment: Actually when i'm trying to escape like this : 
_p.name.replace("'", "''")

My final entry is : l"ange in my db export